# Does the Dirac sea have any mass or gravitational effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gravity, quantum-gravity, dirac-equation

Dirac sea is a model for vacuum which considers the empty space as a sea full of negative-energy particles. Anti-particles are holes in this sea. Dirac sea is used to model Quantum field theory in the paper below:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0701085

Here, Bohmian trajectories are assumed for all particles, even the particles in the Dirac sea.

My question is, if the negative-energy particles filling the Dirac sea have any mass or do they show any gravitational effect BEFORE they are created as real particles?

How about other QFT models? Do particles have any mass/gravitational effect before they are created? I think they do in the short time between creation and annihilation.

Comment: The Dirac sea is an idea that is historically important, but not state of the art. The simplest way to see that there is something wrong with it is to note that this idea does not work for bosons, as it relies on the exclusion principle.

Comment: @marmot I don't know about "state of the art," but there are plenty of particle physicists who think of the Dirac sea as the "real" explanation for the existence of antifermions.

Comment: Well, what can I say? If you meet them, you may want to ask them why this explanation fails to work for bosons. To the best of my knowledge, the modern view is that you have creation and annihilation operators for particles and antiparticles. So the absence of a state with negative energy, i.e. a hole in the Dirac sea, becomes the presence of an antiparticle in the modern view.

Comment: The Dirac sea would exhibit no gravitatonal effects due to the shell theorem.

Comment: @Lewis thanks, but how can we think of the dirac sea as a spherical shell (which is the object of interest in the shell theorem)? why can the particles in the dirac sea be considered to be in a spherical shell?

Comment: @marmot in the state of the art QFT, do particles have any mass (and so gravitational effect) before creation, or they have a mass only after creation?

Comment: Massive particles have a mass, and the mass does not depend on whether or not a particle created. The vacuum is the state with zero particles in, i.e. zero excitations. So in the vacuum no (massive) particle is present.

Comment: @marmot I think vacuum can be considered to have an uncertain number of particles, according to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. This is the fact based on which particles pop in and out of existence. how can a particle which doesn't exist yet have a mass and show gravity?

Comment: @Ali I guess I decouple here. The vacuum is a well-defined state in QFT. The question about the vacuum energy is an unsolved one, and if you are talking about virtual particles, your statement may be considered not absolutely wrong (please excuse the strong language!), but we know how to deal with those in principle. I still insist the Dirac sea is an outdated concept, and I stop here, hoping you find someone who is more sympathetic to this idea.

Comment: The shell theorem is so-named because it usually is applied to a test particle dropped into a hole bored through the center of mass of the earth.  It states that the gravity acting on the particle would be determined only by the  mass contained within a spherical shell centered on the center of mass and with a radius defined by the test particle position.  In the exact center, the effect of gravity would vanish.  For the Dirac sea,(infinite in extent and homogeneous) the  gravitational effect on a test particle would be the same as for the particle at the earth's center of mass.

Comment: BTW @marmont is correct that the Dirac sea concept has been replaced by QFT.  There were several decades, however,  between Dirac's hole theory and the development of QFT.  The shell theorem is the reason that your question was not raised as an objection to hole theory during those decades.

Comment: @Lewis thanks. sorry if I ask absurd questions, I am not an expert. but I have two questions. First, why is the dirac sea perfectly homogeneous? I think in some regions there are holes in the dirac sea which might make it inhomogeneous with respect to a particle which is far away. Second, do the negative-energy particles of the sea have a real mass (which produces gravity) at all? positive-energy particles and anti-particles (holes) certainly do, but if every particle in the dirac sea has mass, the vacuum should have infinite mass! but we know that vacuum does not curve the spacetime.

Comment: @Ali Actually vacuum energy can and does curve spacetime. From gravity perspective it's just a cosmological constant. But from the Standard Model (QFT) perspective it depends on the UV cutoff scale which is the scale at which (presumably) new physics arise.